# Xtext formatting exception

Tags: xtext

When I auto format (ctrl + shift + f)  in my plug in, I get the following exception:

```
!ENTRY org.apache.log4j 4 0 2016-10-13 00:30:23.002
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.formatting2.ContentFormatter$FormattingUnitOfWork  - Error formatting platform:/resource/Test/src/algebra.mcrl2: null

!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.process(NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.java:223)
at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.process(NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.java:214)
at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.process(NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.java:214)
at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.process(NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.java:214)
at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.process(NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.java:214)
at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.process(NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.java:214)
at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.process(NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.java:214)
at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.process(NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.java:214)
at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.process(NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.java:214)
at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.process(NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.java:214)
at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.process(NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.java:214)
at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.getEObjectToTokensMap(NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.java:86)
at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccess.<init>(NodeModelBasedRegionAccess.java:29)
at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.internal.NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.create(NodeModelBasedRegionAccessBuilder.java:57)
at org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.regionaccess.TextRegionAccessBuilder.create(TextRegionAccessBuilder.java:37)
at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.formatting2.ContentFormatter.initRequest(ContentFormatter.java:126)
at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.formatting2.ContentFormatter.exec(ContentFormatter.java:88)
```

with much more entries in the stack trace.

Dow any have suggestion how to solve the problem?

Comment: looks like a bug to me. can you file a ticket at http://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core with a reproducing example attached

Comment: created ticket: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/issues/145#issuecomment-253786576